# Lists and lists of lists issues

Tags: python

I have a program I am writing.  I have limited python experience.  The program takes csv file to create a list of lists.  A txt file takes a string of characters and turns it into a list of ints.  I then have to compare the list to the ints in the list of lists.  This compares DNA for a match.  The program works but for one issue.  One of my csv files has three different strings of DNA to compare, the other has 8.  I can get it to work with either, but it takes an adjustment to the line to create the lists chdnalist and subsequence.  Currently running with [[], [], []] it will only run the smaller list with 3 strings.  I can add a total of 8 [] but then of course it won't work with the set of 3 strings.

Here is a copy of my code:

```
import csv
import sys

def main():

    # TODO: Check for command-line usage
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Missing Files!")
        sys.exit(1)
    # TODO: Read database file into a variable
    dnalist = []
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r", newline = '') as subject_file:
        dnalst = csv.reader(subject_file)
        for row_list in dnalst:
            dnalist.append(row_list)

    # TODO: Read DNA sequence file into a variable
    with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as f:
        sequence = f.read()

    # TODO: Find longest match of each STR in DNA sequence
    chdnalist = [[],[],[]]
    subsequence = [[],[],[]]
    for q in range(1, len(dnalist[0])):
        subsequence[q - 1] = dnalist[0][q]
    for t in range (len(subsequence)):
        chdnalist[t] = longest_match(sequence, subsequence[t])


    # TODO: Check database for matching profiles
    compare(dnalist, chdnalist)
    return

def longest_match(sequence, subsequence):
    """Returns length of longest run of subsequence in sequence."""

    # Initialize variables
    longest_run = 0
    subsequence_length = len(subsequence)
    sequence_length = len(sequence)


    # Check each character in sequence for most consecutive runs of subsequence
    for i in range(sequence_length - 1):

        # Initialize count of consecutive runs
        count = 0

        # Check for a subsequence match in a "substring" (a subset of characters) within sequence
        # If a match, move substring to next potential match in sequence
        # Continue moving substring and checking for matches until out of consecutive matches
        while True:

            # Adjust substring start and end
            start = i + count * subsequence_length
            end = start + subsequence_length

            # If there is a match in the substring
            if sequence[start:end] == subsequence:
                count += 1

            # If there is no match in the substring
            else:
                break

        # Update most consecutive matches found
        longest_run = max(longest_run, count)

    # After checking for runs at each character in seqeuence, return longest run found
    return longest_run

def compare(dnalist, chdnalist):
    for name, *dna in dnalist[1:]:
        dna = list(map(int, dna))
        if dna == chdnalist:
            print(name)
            return
    print("No match")

main()
```

Here is a copy of the small csv file:

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
Bob,4,1,5
Charlie,3,2,5
```

Here is a copy of the large csv file:

```
name,AGATC,TTTTTTCT,AATG,TCTAG,GATA,TATC,GAAA,TCTG
Albus,15,49,38,5,14,44,14,12
Cedric,31,21,41,28,30,9,36,44
Draco,9,13,8,26,15,25,41,39
Fred,37,40,10,6,5,10,28,8
Ginny,37,47,10,23,5,48,28,23
Hagrid,25,38,45,49,39,18,42,30
Harry,46,49,48,29,15,5,28,40
Hermione,43,31,18,25,26,47,31,36
James,46,41,38,29,15,5,48,22
Kingsley,7,11,18,33,39,31,23,14
Lavender,22,33,43,12,26,18,47,41
Lily,42,47,48,18,35,46,48,50
Lucius,9,13,33,26,45,11,36,39
Luna,18,23,35,13,11,19,14,24
Minerva,17,49,18,7,6,18,17,30
Neville,14,44,28,27,19,7,25,20
Petunia,29,29,40,31,45,20,40,35
Remus,6,18,5,42,39,28,44,22
Ron,37,47,13,25,17,6,13,35
Severus,29,27,32,41,6,27,8,34
Sirius,31,11,28,26,35,19,33,6
Vernon,26,45,34,50,44,30,32,28
Zacharias,29,50,18,23,38,24,22,9
```

Here is a copy of one of the text files I have when run in with the small csv file the program will return a match to Bob.

```
AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG
```

This file will return a match to Luna from the large csv file:

```
TCTATTCTTTGAGGATACGCTCGGCCTAGGCGGGGCTAATGGAAGCCAGGCTAATCCGATGTTGCGGTGCACCTCGATACCGTTCTAAAATATCACATCAACGCGCTCCAGTTGTGTGCCAAGGCCCGCTGAAGAGCAATGGAGCACCTACCCGGCCTTCTAACGCTGTCTAAAACTCCAAGCGAATTGCAGATTTTGGTTAGGACCCGTTTAATCTGTGGGCTTTGGTACTATGCAACCAATGGAACCGGTCGGACTCTGATCAGTCCCGACTGACAGGTCTCAAGTAGTTTGCTTACACGTTCTGACCCCCGTGCGCACCGTTGGGCGTACAGCGGTTCGGTCTATGGAATCAAGGAAAATCATTCGTATGGGGACGTAGTCACATAACAGCTGCAGGGAACTATGGAGATGACGAGGGGTCGTTTAGTGGAACGTCAAATGTCCTAACTGGTTCTGAGCTGTCTGGAACGTTGCAGTCAACGTCTACGATCTGGATTCTACAGTCTAGGCGTTCCAAGGGGCACCAGTAAGCTAAGTTGTTTAAATATGGCGGGTGTCGAAATGACGTCCAAAATCGCAAATAAGACAGATAGCAGGGGTGCAACTTAGGTATCTAAGGTAACTCTGACATACCTCATACAACTATCGAACAGTGGATTCCTTGTCGTCCTGTTGTAAACAGTTCAAGTCGGTACATGTTAGCGGGTGGTTTGGACGAGTATACAGGACCTGGCCTACACGGAATGTTTTAGATTCTATGTCCGGCGGGGACATCGCGTGCCGCTAGGATATAATTGGATTGTGGGAAGAATTTGGCCGGATTTTTGGCCTAGACTCGCGCTTCAGACCATACCGTGCGATCAGCACGATTGCTGACAAGCGTCGGTATTAAAGCAGGCTCCTTCCCAGCCAAACTAACCCAACGAAGACATCATGTTTCGCCGAAGTATCTTTGGGAGATGGGCGAATTAATCGCTTAGCGTGGCCGACTTGGGGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGGTTTAAGGGACTTATCCGACCAGAGGGGCAGTTACTTGTGGCGGTCACACGCCAGGACGAGTCTGTTCTTGCTGTGCGTAGATTAGGCTTGATCTGTGACTACAGGCGAATAGTAGGTGTGGGAAACAGAGGGGGGAGCAATGTGATCCCGGGGGGAGTGCTTCCTATACCTCGGTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGGATTATCCCCACCCAATGATCCGATCGCAAGCCTTAATACCATGGCACACCTCTCAACCTACTGATCTTCCATCCGTTTAACCCAGCACTAAGCTGCTCAGTGGTCACACTATGTTCAAGCTTCCGTGACGTGGGATCCTGGGGTCTTCGCAAGGCTAGTTTTGACCATTATCGACGACCGTCACCCTGTGACTGGTTCCCAACAAGGTGTCAAGTTCTAGCCCGTACCTGCAATCGGGAACCTCCGGTGCTTCATGAACCATGGATATAGGAATTATTGGTCTCCTCTCGCGTAGGTAGCGCGAATACCCCCAAGATGACACACTGTGGTGAACTTTGAGGACTCCCAGAAGGGTGACGGGTTATGTGGTTACGCGAAGTCGGCGTATCCACCGCCTAATTTTAAATTCAGCTCGAGCGACACGCGCGCTTCCTGGAAACGTTAGACGGGAAAAACCCCGCCCGAGAATGCGGGTTCCGCGGCCCACTAGGGGGCCCCCCAAGGATCTGACCGCGTATAAGCAATGCACAGCTGTACCATTTCAAATAGGACAGATAGTACCCCCACCGTGACTCGGCCTCAGATAATGGAATACGACCTGGTGACGGCGGTAGGGGTTCTATCTCAGGTATTCAGAGGGTGCATCCAGGTGATTCGTCACGTCCCGATTTCGACCCCACCACAGGATTTGTGCGATGGTAGTCTTGATGCTGTTTGCAGGCGGCCAAGCATCTAGGAGATGCCTCACTGCGCGAGATGAACCGGCGTTTCACAAGGGGACGCCAGGCCTTGCCGTCTCCATAAACCACGAGAAGGTATCGAACGTCAAACGGATAAATGCCGCGATACCGCTCGTTTCGAAGCGGCACTTCGATGGAAATGAGTAGTATGGCCTCGCCACACGACTACTCATCGGCTTGCGCTGACATCAATCCTGGCTGGCTTGAGGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGCTCCATAGGAAGGTGCGGGATAGCGGACAGCTAATCGGACAGAAGGGCCAGCTTGCACTCTCCTATAATTAGCAAGCGCCATACAATTGTAATCACGTATAAAATACAGCTACGTAAGTAATAGAGAGGCTCCCGGACTGTCCGGCGTCCCGCCAGTCTCGTACCAGGAGGTGGGATGGTAGGCAAACGAGCCTACTAGAATTGGGCCACCCTGTGAATAATATGCAGAGGCAACTACAGACGTCCGTCACCTGCCTAGAATCGAGTTCATTGACGGTGGGATATGCTCCGTTACCTGACTGTAGTTCGACTTTGTGGTGCGCACATAACGAGTGTCTACGATGCACAAAGTGTGAGCAAATTAGGAGTGTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTGCCGAGATGTTGGCGGGAAGTGTACGGCTTTGCGTCGTCGAGTGCTACGCAGTGTGCTACACTCCCGCAGCTGAGGCTAGGGCCCGAAACTAGACATTTTTTCTTTTGGCACTTCGTTCCGTATAATGAGTTCCCTCAATTCCCCGTCCGCAAGCCTCAGGATTACAATTAATTATACGGTTAAAGTTGGCTGCCAAGCCCGTTATTGACCGGTACCTGAGTCGAGGGGGGGTTGGGGATAGGCAATTATAGTATTCACTCACAGGACGCTCAGTAATGCCGCCGTTGTACTTCACGTAAGGGCCACAGTTTTTCTACCACAGAGGATGATCTGAGGACAGCGGTGCGTGAAGCCCGCTATTCAGGACACCCTCGAAACCCGTGGTTCACAGACAAAAAATTCGCCGCGGAAGCTGTTGCCCCTATGCCCCGGGTCAGCAAGGAGTCTGGATTTTATTCCAAGACTGCGTCTTTATTTTCTGGTGAGTATGAAATGACTCTGAGAAAATGGTCGAACCACGAGCTAGCTACAGCCACAGTCCGCTCAACTAACTTACCTCTACTCTAACAGTTACACGGCTTCCCGTTTTATGGGAAGAAGCACCTGTTCCTTTCCCAAGCCCCTTATAGCAGAGGTTGGTATTCGGTTGATTTGGAATAGTTAAACAGCGGCTATTTTGTAATCACTTTCCAGTCGGTAAGACATTCGAACCTCGTTTTGACGCTGCTCGCCATCGCGTTCGACTAGGAGTATTCCACTTTTCGGAGAGATGATTACTCATGACGCGGGGAACTCCATGGCTGTCATGCAGGATCTGGGCTAAATAAGATTAGATGTTCAACTGTCGTATACTTACTGCTACCAGCGGTGCTAGGCCCAGGACCCGCCATACCTGGCTATTGATCACTCTACCAGATGTCTCTTGACGAGTTACGAATTGCTGGGTGCTCTTGGAGACGAGTTGAGTCCGTAGTCGTGGCTGGGGAACGGGCGAGTTCGTACGTACCGTTTCAAAGCCCCACGAACCCAACCTCTTAGCCTTAACCCCACATTAGATACCCAAGTTGCATGACGCATTATGCGAGTACGACACTGGTATCGGCTGATCCGTCACTGCTCAAAGTCCAGTGGTTTCCTTATCTCGGGCTGGAAAGTGTAGCTTGTTCCAAACCTTCGAGAGGTTGATCGATGACCGGTTCTCACACACATCTTGCGGAGGGATGCTTGCGATGTGGCTTTACGTCCACCGACGGGCCGACTAGCTGGAAATCACAAACCCCTGCTCCGATAAGGTATTCTCGTTGACTTAGGGTAAACAAAATGCCCGTTACGTCCTAACCGAGTTTCCGGGCCTTCACTACCCGCGAGGGATGTGTAGTGGGGCCATTTACCTAAGCAGATGTACACCGAGTTACGATAGTCACATGGCCATTCAAAGCGTCTCACATAATCGATCGATAGATGATGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCCCGGAGGAAGCTGCGATTGGAATGCGGCTAACTTCGCTCTGCAACATTCTTGGCAGACGGCCCCAATGGCGTAATTTAGGCGTGTGTACCTAAAGTGGTCTACTCCTATGAACCGAATCGCGGGATAAATCGAGTTGGGACTGCTTTGCCTTAATTACATTCACTGATTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGGTCGAGCACGGCTGGCACGTCCGGCTCCATCGCGTCGTAATCCATCCCTATTCGACCAACAAAACCTCAGGGGACGGGATGTGAGTGGGTATCGATCATTATCGAACGCCCATAAGTACTCCACTCATCTGTCTGAAAAGTTTGTCGAGTGCCGCTCTCTGAAGAGTACGATAACTTACTCCAAACACTCTACGCCTAGTGGTCGAAAACACTAAAGGGAAAATACTCACTGACTTACTCTGTCGCTCTACGATTGCCGCGATACCTTAATAAGACACGTATCGGCTGTCGCAGCGATGGATTCCTTAAGCGATACAACTAAGATCAATCGGTGCCGGGCCTACAGCCTGGGCCCTAGCTCCAAAAGTGATAATGGATAGTCGGTTCAAGCGAATTTACACCAGACTGATCCTTTACGGTCATTCCGACCGCCGCATGATACATGCCAAAAGACACTTGTCTTCTTTCCTCTAAAAGACAGACCTTGTTTGCAAGGAGAGCCCAATCGGCACGACCCAAAGGGATTATCAACTGAACTATTATTGCATACTACTAAGCAGACGGACCGTATAGCATCATTGATACCTATTATATTTCCATACACCAACTCCATACGCGATGGGTCGAAACTACAAGCTTCACTTACGTGTACAGCCGCAGGACCCACTCTCTAATCTAGCCAATGACACTACTAATTTGAACATTCCCCAGCGATGAACAGGCACATGAGCGGTCCTCGTACCCACCACGGCCCGCTCAACTGCAAGGGGCCGCTCGGATCAAAGTTTTTCACTAACTCATGTCGAGCAGATCGGCATGCTCAAGATAGTATTTTAGGAGG
```

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` is the csv with names in the first column? Are you asking how to write the section `Find longest match of each STR in DNA sequence` so that it can handle an arbitrary number of columns (`strings of DNA to compare`) ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to initialize empty lists and iterate based on indexes when e.g. [list comprehensions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) will provide a more concise, less error-prone way to accomplish the same result.

Construction of `subsequence` and `chdnalist` can be fixed like this:

```py
# TODO: Find longest match of each STR in DNA sequence
subsequence = [x for x in dnalist[0][1:]]
chdnalist = [longest_match(sequence, s) for s in subsequence]
```

Comment: Thank you!!  Ive been getting my butt kicked on this for over a week now.